# React Native issue on checkPropTypes

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

Native. I am getting this issue:

```
D:\abc\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManage…:71 Warning: checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.checkPropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on npm instead.
```

**Please help me to know this issue.**

My app dependency is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
}
```

Comment: What isn't clear about the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as informative the error is react has moved the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) from react-core to another independent package , so in order to use you need to add that to your project.

add another dependency in package.json

`"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "prop-types": "15.5.8",
}`

and wherever you used to import 
`import {PropTypes} from React` or `React.PropTypes`

you need to `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`